# Can I create two react application in the one spring project?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have two different part of the web application, that is a public site and admin site. And I want to create different independent react application for both of them. For the API I use Spring-Boot. 
Can I do that in my case?
And what I need to add to the webpack.config.js file?

I tried to create one more HTML page and render to that application. But that does not work. Because one react application render only one time.

I expected to run two different react application using one API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main options:

- Split up the 3 applications (spring-boot, react-public, react-admin) into separate repositories and deploy things separately as well.
- Use 1 repo for all with a Maven multi-module build

I am going to assume from your question you want to do option 2.

In that case, create a structure like this:

```
+ project
| - backend-api
| - frontend-public
| - frontend-admin
```

The parent `pom.xml` should refer to the 3 modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>backend-api</module>
    <module>frontend-public</module>
    <module>frontend-admin</module>
</modules>
```

Each of the modules should refer to the parent pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Your Spring Boot project will no longer be able to use the Spring Boot parent, so you need to import the BOM dependency:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In the frontend-* modules, you should create a zip file, that you can then pull into your Spring Boot module using the `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unzip-webapp-public</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
                                <artifactId>frontend-public</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                                <classifier>distribution</classifier>
                                <type>zip</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/public</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>unzip-webapp-admin</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.mycompany.myproject</groupId>
                                <artifactId>frontend-admin</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                                <classifier>distribution</classifier>
                                <type>zip</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/admin</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This will unzip the react applications to `/static/public` and `/static/admin`. As a result, Spring Boot will serve them at `/public` and `/admin` in your application.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will start to re structure my project as u wrote.

Comment: Nicely explained, Wim! My key take aways are: 1) Those two React apps need to be built separately so two build artefacts (the zip files) will be created. 2) The zip files are integrated via Maven's dependency resolution mechanism, unzipped during the build and the content will be copied to Spring Boot's folder for static resources 3) Since the two React apps reside in different folders, Spring Boot serves them under two distinct URLs. Those URLs are the entry points for in this use case endusers and admins.